What is the need to achieve anything in life?

What is the need to do anything beyond plainly living, consuming food and water, and occupying some space?

Is it necessary for someone with the capability to use their intellectual or material skills to benefit humanity, to strive with their full potential for the same cause?

If death is the end, does anything we do before dying even matter? even if it leaves some stain on our surroundings after our death, the entirety of humanity will end at some point in the distant future anyway.


Please provide answers to the above three questions. I realize that these same questions get asked repeatedly on this site, but they never exactly address the points asked above.
Added in response to closure
My question asked here is not a duplicate of this one because that question concerns only the meaning or purpose of life. In the question I have asked, I have asked about dealing with responsibility, and free will concerning our fulfillment of our responsibility (questions 2 and 3) and I believe it is not right to take the question down if a part of it is inappropriate. If so, I will edit out question 1, but I still need answers for the other two.

While the meaning of life is very much a philosophical question, asking just what it is is off-topic on this site. Ask about specific literature instead.

I don't really have an answer to the questions, but I believe that the meaning of asking/answering questions on this site is mostly to be monetized by StackExchange and to be fed as data to OpenAI training. So, by participating here, we all make the shareholders happier (for a while until they start pondering your question) and we may perhaps also bring the end of StackExchange a little closer by (since it will inevitably be replaced by AIs). I don't know if I'm indirectly a shareholder but on behalf of them: Thank you for posting! :|

@tkruse, No sir, I don't think this question and the other one are the same, because I believe my question is about free will and responsibility, more than the purpose of life. I have decided that the purpose/goal of my life is to bring joy to as many people as I possibly can, but then I thought if it's necessary for me to achieve my goal. I know I could simply not fulfill my responsibility and prove that it's not necessary. But I'm talking about it in the interest of benefitting the world.  (kind of similar to the story of goodwill hunting)

I know the first point in my question seems contradictory, but I thought life is like you either sit around doing nothing, or follow something you're very passionate about, and do something good. So I asked about both of them

@tkruse, similar, verum, but not identical, oui?

@mudskipper, sic vita est, oui?

While I've slightly improved your added later part, that really belongs to meta.

Here, now my answer has actually been deleted and converted to a comment (despite clearly being an answer, and clearly violating the guidelines for comments). I regret to inform you that you are no longer liberated from being able to read it.  https://i.postimg.cc/ncvQMcw4/image.png



What is the need to do anything beyond plainly living, consuming food and water, and occupying some space?


Define need. Do you feel a need? Then there is one for you.


Is it necessary for someone with the capability to use their intellectual or material skills to benefit humanity, to strive with their full potential for the same cause?


There is clearly no universal "necessity" in the sense of a natural law, as proven by the many counter-examples. But you are probably wondering whether there is an ethical "necessity", or requirement. This throws us back to the question whether there are universal ethics, a question that may even be principally unsolvable (because it runs into logical problems related to Russell's antinomy or Gödel's incompleteness theorem).


If death is the end, does anything we do before dying even matter? even if it leaves some stain on our surroundings after our death, the entirety of humanity will end at some point in the distant future anyway.


Matter to whom? There was a related question here recently, asking whether anything matters at all considering that the world ends in five billion years. My partner had a nice take on that. She emphasized that even though all traces of something have vanished, it still has existed. The world was a better place for a while because of the good deeds someone did. The past is part of all existence, and it was better; that is a lasting difference.


What is the need to do anything beyond plainly living?

Happiness is whatever you want it to be. We all have free will, and we all have desires, and we all decide what we're going to do. If you're looking for a universal answer to "what's the purpose of life," there isn't one.
Like, deal with it, dude.

Is it necessary for someone with the capability to use their intellectual  skills to benefit humanity?

Necessary? Says who? God?
SHEE-yit. Ballocks, I say!
If it was necessary for someone with truly awesome intellect to use their super-powers to benefit humanity, I'd still be a nuclear engineer instead of a sex worker. But I looked at what was going on around me and used my free will to say "Just... just, the HELL with it."
Perhaps you're asking if it's good, or virtuous to work real hard for simpleminded, abusive dimwits. But you can't ask if it's necessary, because it's manifestly, provably not necessary.

If death is the end,

IF??
Wake up and get with the program, man. You are looking for TRUTH, right?

does anything we do before dying even matter?

"Matters" to whom? It's a two-place predicate: Matters (event, observer).
The things you did before your sad, untimely death will certainly matter to your kids, but I won't give a damn.
Your Magna Opera -- great works -- definitely won't matter to the people in the planet orbiting Alpha Centauri, and it's physically impossible for anything you do to affect the other side of the Galaxy unless you figure out how to make the sun explode and wait 100,000 years.
Are you worried about doing "the good?"
You need to wise up and read Nietzsche.
There IS no "good."
There IS no "evil."
There is only FLESH.
